# Basis for the subspace W orthogonal to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree $≤2$ with inner product given by:

$\left \langle f,g \right \rangle=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt$

Let $f(t)=t+2$, $g(t)=t^{2}-2t-3$, and $h(t)=2t+1$. Find a basis for the subspace $W$ orthogonal to $h(t)$.

Picture can be found here! [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9jI1.png) I was able to do (a) and (b) and reckon I'd need to do (c) properly to make sure that my answer for (d) is correct. Thanks so much!

Comment: Write down what it means to say that $at^{2}+bt+c$ is orthogonal to $2t+1$. You will get an equation satisfied by $a,b,c$. Write $c$ in terms of $a,b$ and plug that into $at^{2}+bt+c$. You should now be able to write down a basis for the orthogonal complement of $h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have seen the Gram-Schmidt procedure, I'll give you a way to solve this problem. We know that the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ is a three dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. We construct a basis for this space by taking your polynomial $h(t)$, and adding the polynomials $x^2$ and $1$, these polynomials are independent and thus gives a basis for the space of polynomials.

We are going to solve problem c) and d) at once by orthonormalizing this set of polynomials $\left\{2t+1,t^2,1\right\}$ using the GS procedure, lets call the resulting set $\left\{p_1,p_2,p_3\right\}$. By the theorem of GS, $p_1$ spans the same space as $h(t)$, and thus we have that the space generated by $p_2$ and $p_3$ is orthogonally to the space generated by $h(t)$ because of the dimension theorem, which says that $$\dim(V)=\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\perp})$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Both $t$ and $1$ appear in the polynomial that spans $W$. How did you know to omit $t$ but not $1$ from the process?

Comment: We need to add two polynomials independent to each other and to $2t+1$ in order to get a basis for the space of polynomials of degree $\leq 2$. An obvious choice is the polynomial $t^2$, which leaves us with only one polynomial to find. Since all polynomials of degree $<2$, except $0$, are independent of $t^2$, we only have to worry about independence with respect to $2t+1$. The only polynomials which are dependent with $2t+1$ are obtained by scalar multiplication of $2t+1$, so we can choose every other polynomial in order to get a basis, so i could also have chosen $2t$ or $2t-1$ or just $t$.